# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 293

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would really appreciate some help with this. It is on a WP-Script WP theme.

Line 293 is in bold (**):

```
}

$output     = '';
$has_teaser = false;

// If post password required and it doesn't match the cookie.
if ( post_password_required( $post ) ) {
    return get_the_password_form( $post );
}

**if ( $page > count( $pages ) ) { // if the requested page doesn't exist**
    $page = count( $pages ); // give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist
}

$content = $pages[ $page - 1 ];
if ( preg_match( '/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $content, $matches ) ) {
    $content = explode( $matches[0], $content, 2 );
    if ( ! empty( $matches[1] ) && ! empty( $more_link_text ) ) {
        $more_link_text = strip_tags( wp_kses_no_null( trim( $matches[1] ) ) );
    }
```

Comment: It says that `$pages` is not an array. But it may be impossible to find the reason with given info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just added some more code. Is it enough now?

Comment: Is this your code, or WP internal library? This piece of code doesn't even show what `$pages` is. My guess is that loading of pages fails for some reason (syntax error in something you wrote? bad configuration? something else?). Describe what happened, did it work before or is this first attempt to make it work?

Comment: It is not my code, it is from a theme for a tube website. After creating extra pages via the theme's UI, this error comes up in the all three extra newly made pages. I guess it is in the first attempt, since it has never been tested before. Which extra info would you need so you could help me, if of course you have the time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This error is being thrown in the WP Core template `post-template.php` when something's trying to access the function `get_the_content()`. That being said the template doesn't look quite like the current release version of WP, there are a few changes. Can you try updating/reinstalling WordPress?

Comment: @Sephsekla I tried reinstalling the latest version of WordPress but the error persists. Any other idea maybe? Thanks in advance

Comment: Guys, for some reason it got fixed by itself. Thanks a lot for your time.